# How can I stop the UI from freezing?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

When I add many items to Canvas why does the UI freeze? Say I have a loop from 1 to 1000. I can only see all the elements after all 1000 of them are added. Why doesn't the Canvas show up items as they are added or removed one at a time?

What can I do to achieve this effect? I want to animate the elements as they are added to Canvas one by one at a time. But the animation doesn't show up because the UI just freezes.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You might find may answer to this question slightly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188766/how-do-i-block-access-to-a-method-until-animations-are-complete/4199546#4199546

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a timer, and add a smaller number of elements on each tick?  That would let you ensure a few refreshes between each add.

On one project with lots of shapes on a canvas, I found it was helpful to pre-allocate and add all the shapes at the beginning, then just toggle their visibility.  I don't know if that's generally useful or just specific to the situation I was in.

Comment: Timer will affect performance badly since I am adding 1000 items. Without timer also it takes 4-5 seconds to build up. Timer will worsen the situatin. I will probably remove animation rather than a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, we use Application.DoEvents() but I feel it is not possible in Silverlight.

Read this post: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/12015/38635.aspx

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is being executed on the UI thread (the same thread that updates the screen).  Hence, when you perform any computationally intensive operations your UI will freeze.  Long running operations have to run in a separate thread in order for the application to remain responsive.  Start a new thread and from within your thread iterate through your loop and instantiate your objects.  To add the objects to the canvas you will have to use a `Dispatcher` to ensure that part of code runs on the UI thread.

```
MyElement element = new MyElement();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => AddElementToCanvas(element));
```

Comment: What thread should the be used to create an instance of `MyElement`?  When there are a large number of UI manipulations to acheive you really have no choice but to perform them on the UI thread.

Comment: You will have to instantiate items ahead of time and store them in a list.  You can then dispatch items onto the canvas in your other thread.  i.e. 
    DoWork doWork = delegate(int j) 
    {
        Canvas.Children.Add(rectangles[j]); 
    };
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(doWork, i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }));
    workerThread.Start();